# Does anyone make multi-grain matzot?

Tags: product-recommendation, matzah

Someone I know is on a high-fiber health-conscious diet. During the year, she only eats multi-grain breads.

She is wondering if anyone makes a "multi-grain" matzah, i.e. a mix of whole wheat, oat barn, perhaps barley, etc. If anyone makes these shmurah, even better. Does anyone know of any such brand and where she can get this in the U.S.?

Comment: Unlikely. Non-wheat matza is generally avoided absent pressing health reasons (eg. wheat allergy). See for instance the Rama (OC 453) and Minchat Yitzchak 9:49

Comment: Whole wheat isn't good enough i take it?

Comment: I've often seen spelt matza.

Comment: @DoubleAA Can you provide a source? It Is true that you rarely see non wheat matzo, but that's just due to the abundance of wheat. Any of the five grains is equally suitable door matzo.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky what's wrong with the sources i already provided

Answer (score 3):

Osem makes non-shmurah matza in both [whole-wheat-with-added-wheat-bran](http://www.makoletonline.com/products/osem-israeli-high-fiber-matzah), as well as [whole-wheat-and-rye](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001GVIRMA). Both are higher in fiber than plain whole wheat.

Comment: Hmmm ... I haven't seen it in U.S. stores. I'll have to look.